# Can we disabled menu items from contextual ribbons?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

In my project I am generating ribbons dynamically using Office.riboon method. But, Issue is that I am not able to disabled the menu items only controls are enabled and disabled.

So, Is there any way to enabled or disabled the menu items using Office ribbon APIs?

[image: Need to hide menu item that mentioned in below image]

[Ribbon API for generating contextual ribbons dynamically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ribbon?view=common-js-preview)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The dynamic ribbon schema provides an "enabled" property for menuItems: Here are the relevant excerpts. Note that menuItemElement inherits the property from actionableElement.

```
"actionableElement": {
        "$comment": "An abstract type represents controls which can trigger an action.",
        "allOf": [
            {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/buttonLikeElement"
            },
            {
                "properties": {
                    "enabled": {
                        "title": "Title",
                        "description": "Specifies whether the control is enabled when the ribbon is generated.",
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": true
                    },
                    "actionId": {
                        "title": "Action ID",
                        "description": "The action to perform.",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "actionId"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "additionalProperties": false
    },
...
 "menuItemElement": {
        "title": "Menu Item Element",
        "description": "A menu item element in a menu.",
        "allOf": [
            {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/actionableElement"
            },
            {
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "title": "Type",
                        "description": "Type of the element.",
                        "const": "MenuItem"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "type"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "additionalProperties": false
    },
```

The whole schema is at: [dynamic-ribbon-schema](https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/office-js/dynamic-ribbon.schema.json).

You can set the "enabled" property using the  Office.ribbon.requestUpdate() method. Examples are at: [Enable and disable Add-in Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands).

Comment: Thanks @Rick your answer is very helpful for me, I have used enabled property in ribbon but, It is working only first time when we create the control but, on the update time ribbon is not updating.

Comment: I need to update the ribbons of menu items dynamically.

Comment: Have you tried the technique described here? https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands#change-the-state-programmatically  If that doesn't work, please show your code and explain what goes wrong.

Comment: Actually, I am talking about menu items not a control. Enabled and Disabled functionality working fine with controls But, Items are not disabled in the menu items.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-t2dvx6?file=src%2Fmain.ts                               I have added config json in above stackblitz editor.

Comment: You may have found a bug. Please raise an issue on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) repo.

Comment: Okay @Rick I will